# How to create IPage Object in C#

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, moq

I am adding unit tests using `Moq 4.13` and [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting?view=visualstudiosdk-2019). I have a function that returns `Microsoft.Rest.Azure.IPage<GenericResourceInner>` and I would like to pass a value of type IPage<[GenericResourceInner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.models.genericresourceinner?view=azure-dotnet)> when this function call is encountered.

How can I create a [IPage<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.rest.azure.ipage-1?view=azure-dotnet) expected value object that I can use in my unit test?

This is what I have tried so far. But I am getting error with the explicit conversion.

```
readonly IPage<GenericResourceInner> _resourceList = (IPage<GenericResourceInner>)new List<GenericResourceInner>() {
            new GenericResourceInner(), 
            new GenericResourceInner(), 
            new GenericResourceInner()};
```

I get an `InvalidCastException` when I run the unit test. How can I create an IPage object?

Thanks for your help!

**[Update 1]**

Based on the comment, I want a Page of type [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Models.Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.models.page-1?view=azure-dotnet). But I don't see any constructors on how I can create an object of this type.

Comment: The `IPage<T>` documentation page lists all of the derived types that you could use. You're using `List<T>` which does not inherit from `IPage<T>` so you can't cast.

Comment: Thanks! I am looking to create something of the type - 
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Models.Page<T> - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.models.page-1?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Just mock the interface and the behavior expected to be used when exercising the test.

Since `IPage<T>` is derived from `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public interface IPage<T> : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>
```

as shown by your provided link and you would like to have the page to be enumerated then simply mock that.

```
var resourceMock = new Mock<IPage<GenericResourceInner>>();
var dataSource = new List<GenericResourceInner>() {
    new GenericResourceInner(), 
    new GenericResourceInner(), 
    new GenericResourceInner(),
    //...
};

resourceMock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(() => dataSource.GetEnumerator());
    
IPage<GenericResourceInner> resourceList = resourceMock.Object;

//...
```

The example above allows for something like

```
foreach(GenericResourceInner x in resourceList) {
    //...do something
}
```

to behave as expected when exercising at test case.

The assumption here is that the subject under test explicitly depends on `IPage<GenericResourceInner>` abstraction.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi! I was not aware of the XY Problem until now. Going forward I will make sure I don't fall into it.